# Anti-concentration of Bernoulli sums

Tags: pr.probability

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be real numbers such that $\sum_i a_i^2 =1$ and let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent, uniformly distributed, Bernoulli $\pm 1$ random variables. Define the random variable

$S:= \sum_i X_i a_i $

Are there absolute constants $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta<1$ such that for every $a_1,\ldots,a_n$

${\mathbb P} [|S| \leq \epsilon ] \leq \delta$ ?

Comment: I don't see how the $c_2n^{-c_3}$ term can help at all. You can always increase $n$ by adding extra $a_i$ which are set to zero, so this term can be made as small as you like.

Comment: So the answer to your question is no. Take $a_1=a_2=1/\sqrt{2}$ and all other $a_i$ set to zero. Then $P(|S|=0)=1/2$.

Comment: I presume this is cheaper than the poser intended. What if all $a_i$ are non-zero?


Comment:  Welcome to MO !

Comment: Luca - can you help with the quantifiers here? George's example seems to show that there's no way to find universal $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ for which this is true for all $(a_i)$ of norm 1 - even if all the terms are non-zero. Obviously if the $c$'s are allowed to depend on $n$ it's trivial as you can just make $c_2\cdot n^{-c_3}$ exceed 1.

Comment: @Anthony: You can still have $a_3$ through $a_n$ as close to zero as you like, so there's no bound vanishing uniformly in $\epsilon$.

Comment: It *is* true that, for any $\epsilon < 1$ is a bound $\delta < 1$ with $\mathbb{P}(|S| < \epsilon) < \delta$ (independently of $n$ and $a_i$). This is one half of the $L^0$ version of the Khintchine inequality. However, $\delta$ does not go to zero as $\epsilon$ goes to zero. My example shows that $\delta\ge1/2$ for instance.

Comment: Oops I didn't think of the obvious counterexample! But I am actually happy with the probability being uniformly bounded away from 1, and with George's answer above. Are there explicit bounds for $\delta$?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer to your amended question is yes. In fact, for any $\epsilon\in[0,1)$ we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(\vert S\vert > \epsilon)\ge (1-\epsilon^2)^2/3.
$$
So, we can take $\delta = 1-(1-\epsilon^2)^2/3$. This is the $L^0$ version of the [Khintchine inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Khintchine_inequality&oldid=295124090).

To prove it, you can use $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j^3]=0$ for $i\not=j$ and $X_i^4=X_i^2X_j^2=1$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[S^4]&=\sum_ia_i^4+3\sum_{i\not=j}a_i^2a_j^2=3\left(\sum_ia_i^2\right)^2-2\sum_ia_i^4\\\\
&\le 3.
\end{align}
$$
The [Paley-Zygmund](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paley%25E2%2580%2593Zygmund_inequality&oldid=366994687) inequality gives
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\vert S\vert >\epsilon)&\ge(1-\epsilon^2)^2\frac{\mathbb{E}[S^2]^2}{\mathbb{E}[S^4]}\\\\
&\ge(1-\epsilon^2)^2/3.
\end{align}
$$

This bound gives $\delta=2/3$ for $\epsilon=0$. By considering the example with $a_1=a_2=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $a_i=0$ for $i > 2$, which satisfies $\mathbb{P}(S=0)=1/2$ we see that it is necessary that $\delta\ge1/2$. In fact, a simple argument noting that the distribution is symmetric under a sign change for $X_1$ (as mentioned by Luca in the comments) shows that $\mathbb{P}(S=0)\le1/2$.

See also the paper [On Khintchine inequalities with a weight](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2586v1), where they prove the same bound as I just did above. Also, using the optimal constants for the $L^p$ Khintchine inequality, as in Lemma 3 of that paper, gives an improved bound for $\mathbb{P}(\vert S\vert\le\epsilon)$ tending to $1-2e^{-2+\gamma}\approx0.517$ as $\epsilon$ goes to zero, which is close to optimal.

Comment: Can't you prove ${\mathbb P} (|S|=0 ) \leq 1/2$ just by observing that, if wlog $a_1\neq 0$, then, for every $x_2,\ldots,x_n$, the vectors  $(+1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $(-1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ give a different value of $S$, and so $S$ can be zero in at most one of the two cases.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I was a bit unsure about that statement, and noticed that rather simple argument (after posting). I edited it now.

Comment: Three remarks regarding George's answer for arbitrary $\epsilon$:  (a.) The same anticoncentration holds not just around 0 but around any number.  (b.) The bound holds with a constant worse than 3 if the $X_i$'s are any independent, not necessarily identical random variables with mean zero and $\|X_i\|_4/\|X_i\|_2 \leq C$ for all $i$.  (The replacement for constant 3 will depend polynomially on $C$.)  See, e.g., Proposition 3.7 here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/prgs-ltfs.pdf  (c.) The $X_i$'s in fact only need to be 4-wise independent, not fully independent.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is part of what's called Littlewood-Offord theory, which has seen a lot of progress lately in work of Tao and Vu and of Rudelson and Vershynin.  Take a look at Section 1.2 and especially Theorem 1.5 of [this paper by Rudelson and Vershynin](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/rv-invertibility.pdf) for more precise results than in George's answer.  (Incidentally, that paper also contains arguments based on the central limit theorem, in the Berry-Esseen form, along the lines of what Igor suggests.)

Comment: One further question which comes to mind (not related to the linked paper though) is the following: Is there a $\delta < 1$ (independent of $a_i$) with $\mathbb{P}(\vert S\vert < 1)\le\delta$? The form of the Khintchine inequality that I know only gives a nontrivial bound for $\mathbb{P}(\vert S\vert < \epsilon)$ with $\epsilon < 1$.

Comment: Your link (to the Rudelson-Vershynin paper) is broken.

Comment: @dohmatob Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the point is to observe that for $a_i$ all equal to $1/\sqrt{n},$ the statement follows from the central limit theorem (since $1/\sqrt{n}$ is precisely the needed normalizing factor). When the $a_i$ are sufficiently slowly varying, you again get a central limit theorem, and hence a similar result (if you look at Feller v 2, section XVI.5, you will see that a condition like 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {\sum a_i^3} = 0$$ is sufficient, though it is probably too strong).